# Why are the standard form of non-homogeneous linear DVQ and the general solution equations true?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We are learning about using the Wronskian matrix to determine linear independence of a set of solutions to find the general solution of an equation:

$$y = c_1 y_1(x) + c_2 y_2(x) +\cdots+c_n y_n(x)$$

where $y_1(x), y_2(x),\ldots,y_n(x)$ are different functions of $x$ that solve the equations and $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n$ are arbitrary constants.

I understand how it is possible that there would be multiple solutions to an equation, and how you could use a matrix to make sure all solutions are unique. 
**What I don't understand is how adding your separate solutions automatically results in a final equation that is also a solution, *y*, or what the arbitrary constants mean in the equation.**

In trying to find the answer I looked at the standard form of a linear DVQ:

[image]

and I realized I don't know why that is true either. I just took it as a given when it was presented to us on the first day of class.

Comment: "[$\ldots$]where $y_1(x), y_2(x),\ldots,y_n(x)$ are different functions of $x$ that[$\ldots$].  "AdamG", can you explain why you put a capital "W" in "Where", as if it were the beginning of a new sentence rather than a part of a sentence already begun?  I've seen this several times every day on stackexchange and in Wikipedia.  I've never understood why people do that. $\qquad$

Comment: I originally had a period after "equation." Then I changed it to a colon and and forgot to capitalize "Where".